# data from mysql database in html

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the template for `login.html`. There is a line: `<h5>&copy; Your Company</h5>`. I want the company name to be pulled from the MySQL database. I have `compnayname.php` file where I get the company name from db. How can I implement this into the following code? Thanks.

```
<div id="container">
    <hgroup id="login-title" class="large-margin-bottom">
        <h1 class="login-title-image">Company</h1>
        <h5>&copy; Your Company</h5>
    </hgroup>

    <form method="post" action="" id="form-login">
        <ul class="inputs black-input large">
            <!-- The autocomplete="off" attributes is the only way to prevent webkit browsers from filling the inputs with yellow -->
            <li><span class="icon-user mid-margin-right"></span><input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" class="input-unstyled" placeholder="Login" autocomplete="off"></li>
            <li><span class="icon-lock mid-margin-right"></span><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="" class="input-unstyled" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"></li>
        </ul>

        <button type="submit" class="button glossy full-width huge">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: make your file `login.php` and include file `company_name.php` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**login.php**

```
<div id="container">

    <hgroup id="login-title" class="large-margin-bottom">
        <h1 class="login-title-image">Company</h1>
        <h5>&copy; <?php include("companyname.php");?></h5>


    </hgroup>

    <form method="post" action="" id="form-login">
        <ul class="inputs black-input large">
            <!-- The autocomplete="off" attributes is the only way to prevent webkit browsers from filling the inputs with yellow -->
            <li><span class="icon-user mid-margin-right"></span><input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" class="input-unstyled" placeholder="Login" autocomplete="off"></li>
            <li><span class="icon-lock mid-margin-right"></span><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="" class="input-unstyled" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"></li>
        </ul>

        <button type="submit" class="button glossy full-width huge">Login</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

**companyname.php**

```
get company_name here and echo it.

echo $company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
First link the companyname.php file to the login.html file..
then do the changes in login.html..

```
<h1 class="login-title-image"><?php echo $companyName; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the prettiest solution but I guess it's the fastest.
Rename login.html to login.php and include the file that gets and prints the name of the company.

`<?php include("compnayname.php"; ?>`

And please fix the typo in your filename ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML file, you need first to rename it login.php to be abled to put php on it. Then with php you'll be fine to call your mysql request, directly in your login.php file, on by including it :

First case

```
<h1>...</h1>
<?php //your sql code
echo '<h5>'.$companyname.'</h5>' ;
?>
</hgroup>
```

Second case (ugly one)

```
<h5><?php include('./companyname.php') ; ?></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file should be a php file instead of HTML file - so save it as "login.php"

You can get the company name from db and store it in a php variable ex (above the HTML tag - can be above the )

**Refer - [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) on how to get values from MySQL db**

```
<?php
       //code to get company name value from db
       $company_name = $row[0];
?>
```

**In the php file just echo the variable name**

```
 <h5>&copy; <?php echo $company_name; ?></h5>
```